# How do I return the corresponding index of the maximum value in a range?

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have an Excel document with 2 columns (A & B - Agent & Calls over 10 mins).

At the bottom of the list I have a total formula which tells me the total calls:

```
=SUM(B2,B3,B4,B4,B5,B6,B7,B8,B9,B10,B11,B12,B13,B14,B15,B16,B17)
```

Under that I would like excel to tell me the Agent with the most calls over 10 mins.

I have tried countless commands including `MAX`, `VLOOKUP`, `DMAX` and `IF` in an array with each other.

Could someone point me in the right direction?

Comment: You should really change your `SUM` formula to `=SUM(B2:B17)`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the combination of `INDEX` and `MATCH`

`=INDEX(A2:A17, MATCH(MAX(B2:B17), B2:B17, 0))`

**EDIT:**

There's a good explanation in http://www.randomwok.com/excel/how-to-use-index-match/

Answer (score 1):

This may help:

```
=OFFSET($A$1;MATCH(MAX(B2:B17);B2:B17;0);0)
```

`MAX(B2:B17)` : Gets highest value of column B

`MATCH(MAX(B2:B17);B2:B17)` : Gets Row Number having highest value

`OFFSET($A$1;MATCH(MAX(B2:B17);B2:B17;0);0)` : Gets cell value when given a reference cell, vertical offset and horizontal offset.

Comment: Unfortunately solution assumes highest value is unique :(

Comment: Well, if OP did not explicitly say to return all that matches... ;) But yes, I suggest adding to your answer the option to accommodate even repeating highest values when you have time. OP will eventually encounter that hitch.